# applying str_split to a column in dataframe

Tags: r, strsplit

I have the following df named i:

```
structure(list(price = c(11772, 14790, 2990, 1499, 21980, 27999
), fuel = c("diesel", "petrol", "petrol", "diesel", "diesel", 
"petrol"), gearbox = c("manual", "manual", "manual", "manual", 
"automatic", "manual"), colour = c("white", "purple", "yellow", 
"silver", "red", "rising blue metalli"), engine_size = c(1685, 
1199, 998, 1753, 2179, 1984), mileage = c(18839, 7649, 45058, 
126000, 31891, 100), year = c("2013 hyundai ix35", "2016 citroen citroen ds3 cabrio", 
"2007 peugeot 107 hatchback", "2007 ford ford focus hatchback", "2012 jaguar xf saloon", 
"2016 volkswagen scirocco coupe"), doors = c(5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3
)), .Names = c("price", "fuel", "gearbox", "colour", "engine_size", 
"mileage", "year", "doors"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some of the words in column 'year' are duplicated. I would like to remove them. As a first step I would like to separate the character string in this column in separate words.
I was able to do it for a separate string, but when I try to apply it to the whole data frame it gives an error

```
unlist(str_split( "2013 hyunday ix35", "[[:blank:]]"))
```

[1] "2013"    "hyunday" "ix35"

```
for( k in 1:nrow(i))
+ i[k,7]<-unlist(str_split( i[k, 7], "[[:blank:]]"))
```

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, k, 7, value = c("2013", "hyundai",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split by one or more space (`\\s+`), and `paste` the `unique` elements together by looping through the `list` output (`sapply(..`)

```
i$year <- sapply(strsplit(i$year, "\\s+"), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=' '))
```

Comment: It works fine. I tried to use sapply, but did not know how to combine two functions  (paste and unique) together.

Answer (score 2):

Working with `dplyr` and `stringr` (with help of `purrr` for working with list), you could do this :

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(newyear = purrr::map_chr(
    stringr::str_split(year, pattern = "[[:blank:]]"), 
    ~ paste(unique(.x), collapse = " ")
    ))
#>   price   fuel   gearbox              colour engine_size mileage
#> 1 11772 diesel    manual               white        1685   18839
#> 2 14790 petrol    manual              purple        1199    7649
#> 3  2990 petrol    manual              yellow         998   45058
#> 4  1499 diesel    manual              silver        1753  126000
#> 5 21980 diesel automatic                 red        2179   31891
#> 6 27999 petrol    manual rising blue metalli        1984     100
#>                              year doors                        newyear
#> 1               2013 hyundai ix35     5              2013 hyundai ix35
#> 2 2016 citroen citroen ds3 cabrio     2        2016 citroen ds3 cabrio
#> 3      2007 peugeot 107 hatchback     3     2007 peugeot 107 hatchback
#> 4  2007 ford ford focus hatchback     5      2007 ford focus hatchback
#> 5           2012 jaguar xf saloon     4          2012 jaguar xf saloon
#> 6  2016 volkswagen scirocco coupe     3 2016 volkswagen scirocco coupe
```

Comment: This is great. I wass having real trouble... can you please explain what the `~ paste(unique...` part does? And how u knew to use that?